# Templates on views of packages for Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have setup some views for my package in laravel.
The problem is, i want to create a template, so that all the views I create, I will use the basic laravel 4 syntax.
So in my controller, i get the action and return the view like this:
`return  View::make('login::interfaces.login');`

Now this returns the view normally, but when i try to use the extend command in order to use a template on that view, i get a view not found error.
So in my login.blade.php i have the following:
`@extends('templates.ui')
@section('content')
//some html 
@end`
My question is, why can it parse the view but not the template?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: show us the code, please

Comment: I resolved it using a controller only solution.
In the controller I added a 
`return  View::make('login::templates.ui')->nest('content' , 'login::interfaces.login');`
statement and it loaded the template and view that way.
I wasn't aware that I could actually use the nesting within the package!
Thank you anyway!